# unity isn't registering the collsion between my player and the obstacles

Tags: c#, 2d, physics, collider

I have tried for some time to fix the problem I'm having, I've looked at tons of different websites and I can't find what is wrong with my script. The player (Where the script is located) has a box collider 2d and a rigidbody 2d while the spike (collider) only has a box collider 2d. I've tried using normal collisions, triggers and everything in between, i've also confirmed that the spelling on the tags are right but I just can't find what is wrong. Here is my code for the collision script:

```
public class Collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    void OnCollisionEnter2d(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "obstacles")
        {

            Debug.Log("Hello");
            GetComponent<GameManager>().endGame();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Languages can be case sensitive void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision).
2d - 2D

Comment: Hi there, thanks for helping me but now im getting another error saying:  Object reference is not set to an instance of an object Collision.OnCollisionEnter2d (UnityEngine.Collision2D collision) (at Assets/scripts/collision.cs:12)